# awk to calculate difference between two files and output specific text based on value

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to check if each `$2` in `file1` falls between `$2` and `$3` of the matching `$4` line of `file2`. If it does then in `$5` of `file2`, exon if it does not intron. I think the `awk` below will do that, but I am struggling trying to is add a calculation that if the difference is less than or equal to `10`, then `$5` is splicing. I have added an example of line 1 as well.

The 6th line is an example of the splicing, because the `$2` value in file1 is `2` away from the `$2` value in `file2`. My actual data is very large with `file2` always being several hundreds of thousand lines. File 1 will be variable but usually ~100 lines. The files are hardcoded in this example but will be gotten from a `bash for` loop. That will provide the input. Thank you :).

**file1**  `tab-delimited` with whitespace after $3 and $4

```
chr1    17345304    17345315    SDHB    
chr1    17345516    17345524    SDHB    
chr1    93306242    93306261    RPL5    
chr1    93307262    93307291    RPL5
chrX    153295819   153296875   MECP2   
chrX    153295810   153296830   MECP2
```

**file2**  `tab-delimited`

```
chr1    17345375    17345453    SDHB_cds_0_0_chr1_17345376_r    0   -
chr1    17349102    17349225    SDHB_cds_1_0_chr1_17349103_r    0   -
chr1    17350467    17350569    SDHB_cds_2_0_chr1_17350468_r    0   -
chr1    17354243    17354360    SDHB_cds_3_0_chr1_17354244_r    0   -
chr1    17355094    17355231    SDHB_cds_4_0_chr1_17355095_r    0   -
chr1    17359554    17359640    SDHB_cds_5_0_chr1_17359555_r    0   -
chr1    17371255    17371383    SDHB_cds_6_0_chr1_17371256_r    0   -
chr1    17380442    17380514    SDHB_cds_7_0_chr1_17380443_r    0   -
chr1    93297671    93297674    RPL5_cds_0_0_chr1_93297672_f    0   +
chr1    93298945    93299015    RPL5_cds_1_0_chr1_93298946_f    0   +
chr1    93299101    93299217    RPL5_cds_2_0_chr1_93299102_f    0   +
chr1    93300335    93300470    RPL5_cds_3_0_chr1_93300336_f    0   +
chr1    93301746    93301949    RPL5_cds_4_0_chr1_93301747_f    0   +
chr1    93303012    93303190    RPL5_cds_5_0_chr1_93303013_f    0   +
chr1    93306107    93306196    RPL5_cds_6_0_chr1_93306108_f    0   +
chr1    93307322    93307422    RPL5_cds_7_0_chr1_93307323_f    0   +
chrX    153295817   153296901   MECP2_cds_0_0_chrX_153295818_r  0   -
chrX    153297657   153298008   MECP2_cds_1_0_chrX_153297658_r  0   -
chrX    153357641   153357667   MECP2_cds_2_0_chrX_153357642_r  0   -
```

**desired output** `tab-delimited`

```
chr1    17345304    17345315    SDHB    intron
chr1    17345516    17345524    SDHB    intron  
chr1    93306242    93306261    RPL5    intron  
chr1    93307262    93307291    RPL5    intron
chrX    153295819   153296875   MECP2   exon
chrX    153295810   153296800   MECP2   splicing
```

**awk**

```
awk '
    FNR==NR{
     a[$4];
     min[$4]=$2;
     max[$4]=$3;
next
}
{
 split($4,array,"_");
 print $0,(array[1] in a) && ($2>=min[array[1]] && 
 $2<=max[array[1]])?"exon":"intron"
 }' file1 OFS="\t" file2 > output
```

**example of line 1**

```
a[$4] = SDHB
min[$4] = 17345304
max[$4] = 17345315

array[1] = SDHB, 17345304 >= 17345375 && array[1] = SDHB, 17345315 <= 17345453 ---- intron
```

Comment: `153295810` in file1 (last records) is not between any of the 3 matched pairs listed in file2.  How does it end up in the output?  Also which difference are you talking, between lower range or upper range, min of the two?

Comment: `153295810` is the splicing I can not figure out... it is +/- 10 (depending on if the lower or upper range is used) away from `153295817`. The difference is between the lower and upper range. Thank you :).

Comment: So it doesn't have to be in the range in file2?  So your condition should convert some of the "intron"s to "splicing" if I understood correctly?

Comment: Your statement "The 5th line is an example of the splicing".  5th line is marked as "exon" not "splicing".  Very confusing as is.  Can you read the question again and fix the inconsistencies.

Comment: I apologize it is the 6th line in the o`desired output` and yes some intron is converted to splicing if they are within -10 from the lower and +10 from the upper. I apologize again and thank you :).

Comment: "because the $2 value in file1 is 2 away from the $2 value in file2" is not valid either.  Please read the question carefully and fix the examples if you're asking for help. I'm out.  Good luck.

Comment: The `$2` value is `153295819` and the closet range for `MECP2` the id is `153295817` to `153296875` so the `$2` value falls within the range resulting in exon. The `$2` value in line 6 is 7 away from the `$2' value resulting in splicing. Thank you very much :).

Comment: Back again.  Not sure how you can't see the conflict here: "The 6th line is an example of the splicing, because the $2 value in file1 is 2 away from the $2 value in file2"  6th value is 153295810.  Both differences 7 and 2 are less than threshold 10.  So, what is the rule?

Comment: I see now, sometimes it takes another pair of eyes to see something that is overlooked, I apologize. If the `$2` value in `file1` can only be `-10` or less than the `$2` value in `file2` to be splicing. In this case since it is `+2` it is exon (falls within the range of $2 and $3 in file2). If the value of `$3`in `file1` is `+10` or less from the `$3` value in `file2` then it is splicing. So I guess the rule is if it is `$2` then minus, but if `$3` then plus? I hope this helps and thank you :).